# How to add nimbus fonts to writeLaTeX.com?

Tags: fonts, overleaf

Is there a way to include nimbus fonts to the writeLaTeX.com workspace?

I tried to follow the example, replacing the custom font TTF with nimbus L, but it doesn't works.

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage{nimbus}`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a cofounder at writeLaTeX.

I've put together an example with one of the Nimbus fonts here:
https://www.writelatex.com/read/ymbcbzpvdbyg

The instructions I followed are here:
http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/latexfonts.php — the main thing is to rename your ttf file to custom.ttf before you start. The .fd and .enc files assume that the ttf is called custom.ttf. If you want to use a different name, you have to change the .fd and .enc files to match.

If it's still giving you trouble, please send us the link to the document that has the problem, and we'll have a look (or provide some more detailed error information here, and we'll try to answer here.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it. I done the same thing yesterdaybut no success, maybe there was something wrong with my preview. The last goal would be use nimbus sans l font on moderncv template.